# how to import data in react from a js file to use in components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This data is in its own .js file I want to be able to use it all over my app how can I?

```
   const posts = [{
          username: "lenard",
          avi: "https://scontent-sjc2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/20905417_730036297205402_7461293070093385728_n.jpg",
        }]
```

I tried importing it into my App.js and passing it down as a prop

```
import posts from './data/posts'; //the js file with the data
import Posts from './components/Posts/Posts'; // the component I want to use it in
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
            <Navigation />
            <Posts posts={posts}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I try to use posts (data) in my Posts.js component I get the error posts is not defined when I try to map through it

```
{posts.map((item) =>
```

but I do not understand why its not defined if I passed it down as a prop.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should export the `posts` in your js file in order to `import` it in other files:

```
export const posts = [{
      username: "lenard",
      avi: "https://scontent-sjc2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/20905417_730036297205402_7461293070093385728_n.jpg",
}]
```

Then you can use

```
import {posts} from './data/posts';
```

Here is a working example:
https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KtsA8KTKvwxTUo2qlW8

If you want to `export default` you will need to create the consts and then export it:

```
const posts = [{
      username: "lenard",
      avi: "https://scontent-sjc2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/20905417_730036297205402_7461293070093385728_n.jpg"
}];

export default posts;
```

And import it regularly:

```
import posts from './data/posts';
```

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kts8LJQBS4I1pprHiSo

Comment: `export default posts = [{
      username: "lenard",
      avi: "https://scontent-sjc2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/20905417_730036297205402_7461293070093385728_n.jpg",
}]`does not work it throws an error I think it needs the const or var before.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `export default const posts = ...` answer updated

Comment: change it to `const posts = [{....}}` then just did `export default posts` but it still says posts is undefined.

Comment: Checking it, give me a minute or two :)

Comment: Check the two examples in my answer

Comment: There are so many people trying to find the answer to this question all over SO & the internet, and this is the only answer. react.js is so dumb.

Comment: What if the Image is in local folder?

Answer (score 1):

Importing default export: If we export something as like export default. Use below syntax to import.

```
import GIVEN_NAME from ADDRESS
```

Importing named values: One module can have number of exports. If our js like that we can use below syntax to import.

```
import { PARA_NAME } from ADDRESS
```

And similarly for multiple such imports we can use a comma to seperate two parameter name within the curly braces.

Importing a combination of Default Exports and Named Values:

```
import GIVEN_NAME, { PARA_NAME, ... } from ADDRESS
```

Exporting syntaxes:-

```
export default GIVEN_NAME
export { PARA_NAME }
```

Go to below site it has a good explanation.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-importing-exporting/

Answer (score 1):

you just forgot to use curly brackets :

```
import {posts} from './data/posts';
```

But if you don't want to use curly brackets, you just need to use (export default) when exporting the posts:

```
const posts = [{
  username: "test",
  avi: "test"
}];
export default posts;
```

Then you can use this :

```
import posts from './data/posts';
```

when importing the posts.

Answer (score 0):

Your imported data must be stored in a unique variable.

so change your `posts={posts}` to `post={posts}`

Import like this

```
import posts from './data/posts';
```

```html
<Posts post={posts}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add here that if you are exporting multiple datasets from a Javascript file, you have to do this:

```
export { articles, otherArticles };
```

Then in the file where you will consume the data:

```
import { articles, otherArticles } from "./yourDataFile"
```